# What should I be concerened about healthwise with a fast metabolism?

Tags: health, metabolism

I seem to have a very fast metabolism, ever since I was a teenager.

For instance I easily consume 500 calories from non-diet sugar based soda a day and then may typically consumer anywhere from 1500 to 2500 calories based on the food I eat, a lot of which is junk food or per-prepared.

I tend to get very little exercise aside from walking where I need to go. This has been the case for years.

I'm not overweight at all, if anything I am slightly underweight as I am just over 6 feet tall and 175 pounds.

I seem to have a decent stamina being able to keep up with most people  in say a random running race or similar spontaneous physical activity. I don't feel tired or anything similar.

If my body is burning off all these calories with no exercise, is this a good thing? What other health effects should I worry about?

Comment: Maybe you should worry about violence from jealous friends after they watch you down the second slice of cake after a steak dinner?

Comment: I tell my jealous friends there is a downside to staying skinny whatever you eat; in my case it is hideous IBS. I assume my guts have to work extra hard to discard all these calories rather than let my body absorb them.

Answer (score 1):

Having a fast metabolism doesn't mean you should lead a lifestyle of **no** exercise and eating junk food.

A Fast metabolism is helping you not gain fat on your body, however not everything is about looks... ie, being slim doesn't imply being healthy, as healthiness is measured in blood vessels and how much fat you have stuck in your blood vessels.

You should consider eating healthier food and exercise so that you lower the risks of health problems when you get older. 
In addition, exercising and eating **Quality food** will **drastically** change your life:

- it will enhance your mood
- boost your energy and focus
- higher self esteem
- it will fight any case of depression that might occur.

What the majority of people don't understand is that the **"quality"** of food is the main cause of **bad health, mood swings , restlessness and depression**.

Junk food, ie food with high levels of **sat/trans fat** and **processed** nutrients, will lower oxygen flow in your blood and thus affect your brain , which requires oxygen to perform .

Comment: If you can add a reference for food quality relating to mood, restlessness and depression I'd be happy to mark your answer as accepted. I'd also appreciate a reference to junk food lowering oxygen flow.

Comment: @MattBronson there are studies and documentaries you can check:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoN3bOzkoJE , http://www.vancouversun.com/health/Fast+food+damage+your+brain+study/5919856/story.html, and others(google the topic). In addition, well why do you drink coffee to get more alert? why do you eat chocolate to feel happy? it is known food is directly linked to mood, and you need good nutrients to enable oxygen reaching the brain, check the following link for example:http://www.livestrong.com/article/517658-foods-for-brain-oxygen/. The point is to be healthy, not accepting/refusing my post.

Comment: the reason I ask for references is I hear that claim a lot, but I am skeptical of it. I've varied between healthy food and junk food at different phases of my life and felt happy when eating both types. I think there is a lot of FUD being attributed to junk foods, although I can't say for sure.

Comment: @MattBronson you have to think on the long run. Think of your body like a brand new ferrari .If you keep fueling it with quality fuel , its engine will still rock after years of usage. If you fuel it with cheap fuel that has residues and not much filtered, the pump that lead fuel to the engine will be stuck and the engine and performance deteriorates. Its your own choice after all, wtv makes u happy

Comment: For sure. I just want to make my choice based on science and not hyperbole.